# PHP using Instagram API error HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, json, instagram, instagram-api

I am using the url like this : 
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=42323d64886122307be10013ad2dcc44&variables=%7B%22id%22:%22555329715%22,%22first%22:12,%22after%22:%22AQDea0aZ27W349lmEWRcuh9xz7sO2Elo-_RDymqEMzT85he8dFwkrV4lbKlii9z7AkWPEbLx_txFKKbHeuotw9c4fY40B-Mm-lF7sfWtq8PUfQ%22%7D

this url working as well is browser but and in code like this :

```
        $insta_id = $ret->users[0]->user->pk;
    $link1 = "https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=42323d64886122307be10013ad2dcc44&variables=%7B%22id%22:%22".$insta_id."%22,%22first%22:12,%22after%22:%22AQDea0aZ27W349lmEWRcuh9xz7sO2Elo-_RDymqEMzT85he8dFwkrV4lbKlii9z7AkWPEbLx_txFKKbHeuotw9c4fY40B-Mm-lF7sfWtq8PUfQ%22%7D";
    $response1 = file_get_contents($link1);
```

What I get before call my function is :

```
Message: file_get_contents(https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=42323d64886122307be10013ad2dcc44&variables=%7B%22id%22:%22492948834%22,%22first%22:12,%22after%22:%22AQDea0aZ27W349lmEWRcuh9xz7sO2Elo-_RDymqEMzT85he8dFwkrV4lbKlii9z7AkWPEbLx_txFKKbHeuotw9c4fY40B-Mm-lF7sfWtq8PUfQ%22%7D): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

Any Idea how resolve this problem ? Many thanks

Comment: In your browser you have username and password or token saved in cookie.
You need to get Auth to get access to this page.

Comment: @Avihaym no I don't set these anywhere. for every page I send request I need Auth ?if it's needle please tell me a referral please . I really don't how get users media with user id from instagram

Comment: take a look on their API: https://www.instagram.com/developer/secure-api-requests/